# Is it possible to deploy a dotnet core application on jboss-eap-6?

Tags: jboss, .net-core

I am researching the possibility of deploying a *dotnet core application* on Jboss EAP, but have not found anything stating if it is possible or not. On the Red Hat site I found information about deploying dotnet core application in OpenShift, but nothing about JBoss EAP.

Is it possible to deploy a dotnet core application on Jboss EAP?

Comment: I have a similar query.can anyone please comment on this.